Why can not install photoswipe on laravel 11 site?
I try to add photoswipe on laravel 11  / livewire 3  site, as I want to use this https://mary-ui.com/docs/components/image-gallery
library.
I run command
npm i photoswipe --save

and in file resources/js/app.js added lines with photoswipe files:
import './bootstrap';

import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox';
window.PhotoSwipeLightbox = PhotoSwipeLightbox ;

import 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css';

But opening a page with image-gallery :
<x-mary-image-gallery :images="$currencyImages" class="h-40 rounded-box" />\

I got error in console of my browser :
livewire.js?id=923613aa:1120 Alpine Expression Error: PhotoSwipe is not defined

Expression: "init() {
        const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
            gallery: '#gallery-mary5c504b362297237df4e3762cb5516df6',
            children: 'a',
            showHideAnimationType: 'fade',
            pswpModule: PhotoSwipe
        });

        lightbox.init();
    }"

What did I miss?
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
"livewire/volt": "^1.0",
"robsontenorio/mary": "^1.35",
...

"dependencies": {
    "photoswipe": "^5.4.4"
}

Changed CODE :
I added code you provided into resources/js/app.js and got another error:
Alpine Expression Error: PhotoSwipeLightbox is not defined

Expression: "init() {
                const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
                    gallery: '#gallery-mary5c504b362297237df4e3762cb5516df6',
                    children: 'a',
                    showHideAnimationType: 'fade',
                    pswpModule: PhotoSwipe
                });

                lightbox.init();
            }"



<div x-data="{
            init() {
                const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
                    gallery: '#gallery-mary5c504b362297237df4e3762cb5516df6',
                    children: 'a',
                    showHideAnimationType: 'fade',
                    pswpModule: PhotoSwipe
                });

                lightbox.init();
            }
        }">
        <div id="gallery-mary5c504b362297237df4e3762cb5516df6" class="pswp-gallery pswp-gallery--single-column carousel h-40 rounded-box">
            <!--[if BLOCK]><![endif]--><!--[if ENDBLOCK]><![endif]-->
        </div>
    </div>

Changed CODE # 2:
As that is laravel/livewire volt component I added next in blade file:
...
<script type="module">

    import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox';
    import 'photoswipe/style.css';
    const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({   gallery: '#gallery-mary5c504b362297237df4e3762cb5516df6',   children: 'a',   pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe') });
    lightbox.init();

</script>

and calling this volt component with code :
<fieldset class="border border-solid border-gray-300 p-3 d2">
    <legend class="text-xl">Gallery of images</legend>
    11111   @livewire('currencies-images-gallery', [ 'currencyLinks' => true], key("currencies-images-gallery"))
    22222
</fieldset>

I got next errors :

and what I see under code :

Actually I do not think we need such code, as that is livewire/mary-ui wrapper(Here https://mary-ui.com/docs/components/image-gallery)
I think must be some specific laravel/livewire decision.
Changed CODE # 3:
I have already installed maryUI, so I need manually to add photoswipe js and CSS in my blade file where I call maryUI images library ?
Looking at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/photoswipe I removed priorly added js code and added into my blade file :
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/5.4.4/photoswipe.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/5.4.4/photoswipe-lightbox.esm.min.js"></script>

<div>
    resources/views/livewire/currencies-images-gallery.blade.php
    <x-mary-image-gallery :images="$currencyImages" class="h-40 rounded-box" />
</div>

But I got next error :

I tried to add the same 2 files into head block of my  layout file resources/views/components/layouts/app.blade.php - But got the same error.
Did I use valid files? What is wrong ?
Thanks in advance!

try:
import 'photoswipe/style.css';

const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
  gallery: '#my-gallery',
  children: 'a',
  pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe')
});
lightbox.init();``` in [here](https://photoswipe.com/getting-started/)

Please take a look at Changed CODE

put it inside a <script type="module">

Please take a look at Changed CODE # 2

since maryUI has a wrapper around the photoswipe, why don't you add those js and CSS in the <head>?

Please take a look at Changed CODE # 3

Just to check, are you sure you added the cdns inside head in the app.blade.php or what ever your primary blade file? there are 3 cdn files for photoswipe and you only added 2 (different versions too).

In a link I provided there are 5 links. Which file I need also include ?

@Mr. Kenneth, could you please which file have I to include into  app.blade.php file ?  From https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/photoswipe source ?

@PetroGromovo on the first link that you provided, there are 3 cdn links.

You used npm install, but in the mary-ui link, it uses cdn. Try to use CDN
